# Seperate IP from port in CSV file using sed/awk

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I am using following to create a csv with the output as shown below. Now, from the output csv I want to split the ip address and port names in different columns and display only process id in last column.

Script is:-

```
netstat -anputw |  awk '{if ($1 == "tcp") print $1,",",$4,",",$5,",",$6,",",$7}' > $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv
netstat -anputw |  awk '{if ($1 == "udp") print $1,",",$4,",",$5,",",",",$6}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv
```

Output in CSV is like:-

```
tcp      127.0.0.1:25    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1112/sendmail
tcp      192.168.0.38:22     192.168.10.143:62998    ESTABLISHED     3084987/sshd
```

Now, I wish to split ip address and ports (comma seperated) and from last column, trim the text and display only process id. Lastly, the first column for this CSV should be the IP address of the host name of which the script is run(displayed for each of the rows). So, output will be like below:-

```
192.168.0.22  tcp  127.0.0.1     25  0.0.0.0         *       LISTEN        1112
192.168.0.22  tcp  192.68.0.38   22  192.168.10.143  62998   ESTABLISHED   3084987
```

Any pointers how can I achieve this in the csv output?

Comment: You do not need to test for both `tcp` and `udp`, then filter it out in `awk`.  If you read the man for `netstat`, you see that `t` is for `tcp` and `u` is for `udp`.  So `tcp` info = `netstat -anptw` and `udp` info = `netstat -anpuw`

Answer (score 1):

You can be reasonably sure that the output will not contain `:` or `/` anywhere else on the line. So simply replace those characters with a tab:

```
... output | sed 's/:/\t/g' | sed 's/\//\t/g'
```

Now all your fields are separated. Just use awk to change ordering the way you want:

```
... output | sed 's/:/\t/g' | sed 's/\//\t/g' | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'
```

The above will skip `$8` which you don't want, and I don't see the host IP in your input, but if you have that, you will have to adjust the indices to include it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am using this to get the IP address of my hostname:- ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.inet (addr:)?(([0-9].){3}[0-9])./\2/p'                                              Can I get this IP address printed as the first column in the output CSV file? Can this be included as a part of awk which I have used? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like with your previous question, you're approaching this all wrong. You don't need a bunch of separate commands and pipes. You don't even need multiple awk commands. You can do everything you want in one simple awk command.

You didn't provide us the output from `netsat` so we could see what the awk input looks like so this it just rough guess but all you need is something like:

```
netstat -anputw |
awk '
   BEGIN {FS="[ :/]"; OFS=","}
   $1 == "tcp" {x=$8; y=$9}
   $1 == "udp" {x=""; y=$8}
   {print $4,$1,$5,$6,$7,x,y}
' > $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv
```

replace "x" and "y" with more meaningful names if you like, I just don't know what those values represent.

If you updated your question to show the sample input (i.e. the output from netstat) plus the expected output given that input we can improve/verify the script and generally help you more.